# Reference for questions like $x_n=\frac{1}{{2(2^2 - 1)}} + \frac{1}{{3(3^2 - 1)}} + \cdots \;. $, $x_n=(1-\frac{1}{3})^{2}...(1-\frac{2}{n(n+1)})^{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, soft-question

My exam tests these model type questions:

I've already asked the following question here on math.stackexchange and got an answer for it.

Find the value of $ \frac{1}{{2(2^2 - 1)}} + \frac{1}{{3(3^2 - 1)}} + \frac{1}{{4(4^2 - 1)}} + \cdots \;. $

Then i couldn't solve the following question on another test.

$x_n=(1-\frac{1}{3})^{2}(1-\frac{1}{6})^{2}........(1-\frac{2}{n(n+1)})^{2}$

The latter question too has already been answered on math.stackexchange.

But I don't want to play catchup with every single question of this type. The trouble is the standard undergraduate texts I have cover all the tests for convergence like comparison test, ratio test and root test. But the problems I mentioned earlier seem to be more competitive exam/Olympiad oriented problems that seem to need a lot of ingenuity. So, I need a good reference book/material for confronting this topic head-on. Could you please share any references to resources you know of? Thank You.

Comment: Don't know which book to recommend.  However, +1 to your question.  You nailed the situation dead-on.  You need to find the right book.

Comment: For what it's worth, my first try on the first problem that you presented in your question accidentally worked - combining the ideas of partial fractions and telescoping series.  However, these are only two of the many possible tools to attack problems like these, and I agree, the problem is that you need to be taught just about every tool possible for these kinds of problems.  That would include when you could use uniform convergence to conclude that the derivative of a summation is the summation of the derivatives and the integral of a summation is the summation of integrals.

Comment: Well, some of my friends who compete in Olympiad read [this](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/11572) book which contains enough about sequences. I myself never read it though. It's a just one of the volumes.

Comment: Personally, I have never seen or heard of an orderly collection of these types of tools, in the same way that I haven't seen an orderly collection of **advanced** integration techniques.  I have seen the standard well organized collection of elementary integration techniques.  Apparently, there is no prestige/profit-motive for an individual professional academic to organize/publish such material.  You would never be able to structure a college course around it, I would guess.

Comment: Typo in my first comment: intended **uniform continuity**, rather than uniform convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to [look](https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-4/) at *Problems in Mathematical Analysis 1* by W.J. Kaczor and M.T. Nowak. The book contains problems about real numbers, sequence and series.

You learn the techniques of problem solving by only solving problems.

The above book contains only problems but it requires a good hold on theory to solve them and nevertheless you will learn typical techniques in solving questions related to sequence and series. Also the book contains solutions.

The problems that you mentioned in your question  can be found in this book!(may not have the exact wording )

There are second and third volume of the book which covers continuity, differentiability and integration.